# Ambiguous rules and predicate behavior in Xtext

Tags: dsl, xtext

I am stuck with the following ambiguous rules in Xtext:

UnaryExpression returns ExpressionAtom:

```
..................

| EXISTS? '(' SelectStatement ')'

| '(' Expressions ')'   
                   //nestedExpression
```

;

When I generate artifacts I get a warning about multiple alternatives. The '(' token is the source of ambiguity.

If I use a predicate "=>" to select the first alternative (i.e., the SelectStatement rule), I ended up with a never-reached alternative2. the SelectStatement rule starts with the 'select' keyword. I thought that if the selected alternative fails, the parser will automatically try the second alternative, but it seems that it is a one-way parsing. What should I do to force the parser to try other alternatives if the chosen one fails?

Comment: maybe you can introduce backtracking. but i am not sure if this would be a good idea. maybe you can also move both rules into 1

Comment: Hi Christian, I thought about merging the two rules into one but couldn't handle the facultative (Exists)?. Should I validate it manually using java? Would you please elaborate on back-tracking?

Comment: yes you dont always have to do every constraint inside the grammar. often you can rule out bad combinations with a validation as well

Comment: Thanks for your feed back. Why backtracking is a bad idea? I have faced similar ambiguities with no possible rules combinations.

Comment: i assume it will have notable performance implications.